# C giving wrong answer to calculation

Tags: c, math

I am coding a very simple program in C but I keep getting wrong answers to calculations that I am doing. The final output that I want needs to have no decimal places so I am using `int` as the data type even though the answer will not be an integer. Here is the code:

```
int numberOfInches = (100/254)*101;
```

I either get the answer 0 if I use `int` as the data type or crazy long numbers if I try using `float` or `double`. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try `101*100/254;`

Comment: Just tried it, no improvement

Comment: The `/` operator with two integers performs an integer division. So `100 / 254` will always produce `0`. What you want is `float numberOfInches = (100/254.0)*101;`

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the behavior of integer division in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)

Comment: What `printf()` code did you use that resulted in "crazy long numbers".  I suspect that is the key to code's problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
100 / 254
```

This is integer division, which will get `0`. You then multiply by `101`.

To do floating point division, at least one of the operands of `/` must be floating point:

```
int n = (int)((100. / 254.) * 101.);
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it will give 0.

```
int numberOfInches = (100/254)*101;
```

When it will calculated first it will evaluate inner bracket.
so `(100/254)` will be 0 And when you multiply `0` to `101`, i.e `0*101 = 0`.

It will be `0`.

To get the correct output, use the following.

```
int numberOfInches =(int)((100.0/254)*101);
```

Answer (score 1):

When both operands of the `/` operator are integer, it performs integer division, i.e. the result is the quotient with the fraction part trucated.  The result of `100/254` is less that 1, so it rounds down to 0.

You can either make one of the constants floating point:

```
(100.0/254)*101
```

Or you can do the division last:

```
(100*101)/254
```

Answer (score 1):

You use an int. The results are rounded to the nearest int value:

100/254 = 0 THEN 0 * 101 = 0 SO, final result is 0.

I think you can do something like :

```c
int numberOfInches = 100 * 101 / 254;
```

result: 100 * 101 = 10100 THEN 10100 / 254 = 39.7xxxxxx SO, final result is 40.

Answer (score 1):

Division in parentheses is integer-type, so 100/254=0. If you want to calculate value with a fractional part try:

```
int numberOfInches = (100.0 / 254.0) * 101.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using float ? try `100.0f/254.0f`